# What JS scope can an anchor tag's href access?

Tags: javascript, html, scope, anchor

I have an `<a>` tag and plan to call a JavaScript function with it:

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething();">link</a>
```

What scope does that JS function have to be declared in to be accessible? Must it be global?

Comment: skip your plan to use inline javascript

Comment: Global, yes. It'd be better to not do that.

Comment: yes is has to be global. Ideally you would not use inline JavaScript.

Comment: Assign event handlers in code instead, so that you define the scope rather than have to have your code available everywhere.  Check out [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [eventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - that should be more than enough to get you going.

Comment: Also `<a>` tags should really be for links; use `<button type=button>` tags for clickable widgets that do other things.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments this is generally now how buttons should be handled, however to answer your question the above code will look in global scope for the `doSomething` function. See below an example.

```js
function TestFunction() {
  console.log("This function is defined in global scope!"); 
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:TestFunction()">Click me!</a>
```